# How to reduce running time of matlab code used for face recognition(PCA based)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis, face-recognition

My code works in the following manner:

List item. First, it obtains several images from the training set
After loading these images, we find the normalized faces,mean face and perform several calculation.
Next, we ask for the name of an image we want to recognize
We then project the input image into the eigenspace, and based on the difference from the eigenfaces we make a decision.
Depending on eigen weight vector for each input image we make clusters using kmeans command.
I have divided total code into 5 parts and i displayed running time taken by 5 parts of code.

**PART1**

```
tic
clear all
close all
clc
% number of images on your training set.
M=50;

%Chosen std and mean. 
%It can be any number that it is close to the std and mean of most of the images.
um=60;
ustd=32;

%read and show images(bmp);
S=[];   %img matrix

for i=1:M
    str=strcat(int2str(i),'.jpg');   %concatenates two strings that form the name of the image
    eval('img=imread(str);');

       [irow icol d]=size(img); % get the number of rows (N1) and columns (N2)
       temp=reshape(permute(img,[2,1,3]),[irow*icol,d]);     %creates a (N1*N2)x1 matrix
    S=[S temp];         %X is a N1*N2xM matrix after finishing the sequence
                        %this is our S
end


%Here we change the mean and std of all images. We normalize all images.
%This is done to reduce the error due to lighting conditions.
for i=1:size(S,2)
    temp=double(S(:,i));
    m=mean(temp);
    st=std(temp);
    S(:,i)=(temp-m)*ustd/st+um;
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.425070 seconds.

**PART2**

```
tic
%show normalized images

for i=1:M
    str=strcat(int2str(i),'.jpg');
    img=reshape(S(:,i),icol,irow);
    img=img';

end


%mean image;
m=mean(S,2);   %obtains the mean of each row instead of each column
tmimg=uint8(m);   %converts to unsigned 8-bit integer. Values range from 0 to 255
img=reshape(tmimg,icol,irow);    %takes the N1*N2x1 vector and creates a N2xN1 matrix
img=img';       %creates a N1xN2 matrix by transposing the image.

% Change image for manipulation
dbx=[];   % A matrix
for i=1:M
    temp=double(S(:,i));
    dbx=[dbx temp];
end

%Covariance matrix C=A'A, L=AA'
A=dbx';
L=A*A';
% vv are the eigenvector for L
% dd are the eigenvalue for both L=dbx'*dbx and C=dbx*dbx';
[vv dd]=eig(L);
% Sort and eliminate those whose eigenvalue is zero
v=[];
d=[];
for i=1:size(vv,2)
    if(dd(i,i)>1e-4)
        v=[v vv(:,i)];
        d=[d dd(i,i)];
    end
 end

 %sort,  will return an ascending sequence
 [B index]=sort(d);
 ind=zeros(size(index));
 dtemp=zeros(size(index));
 vtemp=zeros(size(v));
 len=length(index);
 for i=1:len
    dtemp(i)=B(len+1-i);
    ind(i)=len+1-index(i);
    vtemp(:,ind(i))=v(:,i);
 end
 d=dtemp;
 v=vtemp;


%Normalization of eigenvectors
 for i=1:size(v,2)       %access each column
   kk=v(:,i);
   temp=sqrt(sum(kk.^2));
   v(:,i)=v(:,i)./temp;
end

%Eigenvectors of C matrix
u=[];
for i=1:size(v,2)
    temp=sqrt(d(i));
    u=[u (dbx*v(:,i))./temp];
end

%Normalization of eigenvectors
for i=1:size(u,2)
   kk=u(:,i);
   temp=sqrt(sum(kk.^2));
    u(:,i)=u(:,i)./temp;
end

toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.350561 seconds.

**PART3**

```
tic
% show eigenfaces;

for i=1:size(u,2)
    img=reshape(u(:,i),icol,irow);
    img=img';
    img=histeq(img,255);

end


% Find the weight of each face in the training set.
omega = [];
for h=1:size(dbx,2)
    WW=[];    
    for i=1:size(u,2)
        t = u(:,i)';    
        WeightOfImage = dot(t,dbx(:,h)');
        WW = [WW; WeightOfImage];
    end
    omega = [omega WW];
end

toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.991261 seconds.

**PART4:**

```
tic
% Acquire new image
% Note: the input image must have a bmp or jpg extension. 
%       It should have the same size as the ones in your training set. 
%       It should be placed on your desktop
ed_min=[];


srcFiles = dir('G:\newdatabase\*.jpg');  % the folder in which ur images exists
for b = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('G:\newdatabase\',srcFiles(b).name);
    Imgdata = imread(filename);

        InputImage=Imgdata;

InImage=reshape(permute((double(InputImage)),[2,1,3]),[irow*icol,1]);
temp=InImage;
me=mean(temp);
st=std(temp);
temp=(temp-me)*ustd/st+um;
NormImage = temp;
Difference = temp-m;

p = [];
aa=size(u,2);
for i = 1:aa
    pare = dot(NormImage,u(:,i));
    p = [p; pare];
end


InImWeight = [];
for i=1:size(u,2)
    t = u(:,i)';
    WeightOfInputImage = dot(t,Difference');
    InImWeight = [InImWeight; WeightOfInputImage];
end
noe=numel(InImWeight);


% Find Euclidean distance
e=[];
for i=1:size(omega,2)
    q = omega(:,i);
    DiffWeight = InImWeight-q;
    mag = norm(DiffWeight);
    e = [e mag];

end
format long

z(b,:)=InImWeight;

end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 36.058315 seconds.

**PART5**

```
tic
%disp(ed_min);
%z

IDX = kmeans(z,5);
clustercount=accumarray(IDX, ones(size(IDX)));

disp(clustercount);
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 3.219573 seconds.

Profile Summary snapshot

[image]

**Question:PART4 code is taking more time(36 seconds).What is the solution for this?I just used 50 training images but i need to work on 1200 training  images.What is the method to improve performance?**

Comment: Use the profiler (http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to get a better understanding of just where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Agree with @David: Use the profiler to profile your code.

Comment: @David I posted profile summary.imread command taking more time.Dot operator is taking more.So what is the solution?

Comment: I don't know. It is being called 3039 times, which seems like a lot since you said you are only using 50 images at the moment. I'd look into that, see what matlab is opening all those times maybe. (Maybe `length(srcFiles)` isn't doing what you are anticiapting, I'm not sure)

Comment: @David Iam using 1200 images for training set.There are 2900 test images in my database.

Comment: @David 3039 calls is for 100 training set images.But iam using 1200 images for training set.There are 2900 test images in my database.

Comment: @David Profile summary is for just 50 training set images + 2989 test images(3039 imread calls).But i need to work on 1200 training set images + 2989 test images(4189 imread calls).So it takes too much time.I hope you got my point.